# Tidesdk doesn't work CSS

Tags: css, tidesdk

i can't do somethings with css in tidesdk

I tried to do a css circles, i'm using 1.3.1-beta, but it doesn't work, i don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Can you help me?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="advanced" class="circle"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

and i use this

```
.circle {
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
}

#advanced {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(45px 45px 45deg, circle cover, yellow 0%, orange 100%, red 95%);
background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(45px 45px, circle cover, yellow, orange);
background-image: radial-gradient(45px 45px 45deg, circle cover, yellow 0%, orange 100%, red 95%);
-webkit-animation-name: spin;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-moz-animation-name: spin;
-moz-animation-duration: 3s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
-ms-animation-name: spin;
-ms-animation-duration: 3s;
-ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

i used this in chrome and this work but not in tidesdk app

Edit:

I found this old method to do blur, it's not conventional, but it looks like TideSDK does'nt accept css3 =(

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div />
<div class="blur" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{ overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 200px;
height: 200px;}
#container div{ 
  position: absolute; 
 left: 0; 
  top: 0; 
 z-index: 0; 
  width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border-radius: 40px;
background: orange;
}
#container div.blur:hover{opacity: 0.6; background: white;}
#container div.blur{opacity: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems tideSDK have problems with percentage border radius and the new gradient syntax `-webkit-radial-gradient`. I suggest you to use the old syntax for the gradient. You can find the working code sample below. Modify the colors and the color positions as you wish.

```
.circle {
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#advanced {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 40% 40%, 20, 50% 50%, 250, from(yellow), to(red));
}
```

For more information about `-webkit-gradient` syntax, read [this article](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/radial-gradients/).

Comment: You are right, some of the methods not working properly but this sample works on tidesdk application without a problem.